# PHP Enviar email con adjunto Base64

Tags: php, email, base64

resulta que estoy intentando enviar un email mediante PHP que contenga un adjunto.
Este adjunto es un archivo que obtengo de base de datos. Es un string de un base64.

```
mail($toAddress, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

El email se envía sin problemas pero no encuentro la solución a cómo añadir el archivo como adjunto.

Un fragmento del base64 en cuestión:

```
"data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcKJYGBgYEKCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwKL0ZpbHRlciBbIC9BU0NJSTg1RGVjb2RlIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZSBdCi9MZW5ndGggNDI4Cj4+CnN0cmVhbQo4O1hdTz5FcU5AJScnT19AJWVAP0o7JSs4KDllPlg9TVI2Uz9pXllnQTM9XS5IRFhGLlIkbElMQCJwSitFUCglMApiXTZham1OWm4qIT0nT1FaZVFeWSosPV0/Qy5CK1xVbGc5ZGhEKiJpQ1s7Kj0zYG9QMVshU14..."
```

Comment: En la documentación hay un [comentario con un ejemplo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php#125168).

Answer (score 0):

Voy a asumir que en la variable $message ya tienes el cuerpo del body, deberías hacer una separación junto con otro encabezado llamado `Content-Transfer-Encoding` yo utilizo como perimetro la fecha codificada md5 y luego envías otro encabezado con el archivo adjunto:

Quedaría asi:

```
$separador= md5(time());

$message .= "--$separador\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=$archivo_64\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archivo_64\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
$message .= chunk_split($file_content) . "\r\n";
$message .= "--$separador--\r\n";

mail($toAddress, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

IMPORTANTE:

En tu ejemplo ya tienes el base 64 desde la base de datos, que en tu caso sería colocar esa respuesta de la base de datos en la variable $archivo_64 que aparece en el ejemplo, si no la tienes convertida podrías hacerlo asi:

```
$archivo= "./documento.pdf";
$archivo_64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($archivo));
```

...y como aclaratoria, él `chunk_split()` sirve para fragmentar el archivo en base 64 y cumplir con los estándares RFC 2045 sobre el envío de correos. ( https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.chunk-split.php )